# Javascript Inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm fairly new to javascript, and I'm studying inheritance.  I'm trying to understand the code below, but I don't quite get what lines 3 and 4 are all about. For one thing, why is the child's prototype property being set on line 2 the parent object, only to be set to something else on the following line. And I don't understand the arguments for the call() method.  I thought the 1st arg was supposed to be the function context for Array.prototype.slice(). So why is 1 passed in? And the second arg seems to be the arguments object for Function.prototype.extend(). But I thought you needed to use apply() if the arguments to Array.prototype.slice() are in the form of an array. Anyway, I seem to be missing the whole point of this small block of code. Any insights by more experienced programmers would be much appreciated.

Thanks.  Mike H

Code snippet comes from:
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/calling-parent-methods-in-javascript.html#fbid=D89pEqSy7xl

```
Function.prototype.extend = function(parent) {
  var child = this;
  child.prototype = parent;
  child.prototype = new child(Array.prototype.slice.call(1,arguments));
  child.prototype.constructor = child;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is correct. Please don't follow that tutorial.

Comment: I agree, this code just looks wrong.

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain.

Comment: The following may be better to explain prototype, constructor function and their purpose: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the line #3 in the code is with the parameters inverted, but let's try to make things clearer following your questions:

> For one thing, why is the child's prototype property being set on line 2 the parent object, only to be set to something else on the following line

It's just holding the `child object` so it can be instantiated to define the child prototype chain

> And I don't understand the arguments for the call() method. I thought the 1st arg was supposed to be the function context for Array.prototype.slice(). So why is 1 passed in? And the second arg seems to be the arguments object for Function.prototype.extend().

If you check [this url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), you'll see that it takes two arguments, the second being optional: `array.slice(begin[, end])`; That said, arguments should be the first argument to `.call()`, as it is the context, as you've already pointed out.

> But I thought you needed to use apply() if the arguments to Array.prototype.slice() are in the form of an array.

You're also right about the `arguments` form, it should be an array. And guess what? It is... :)
Check this http://jsfiddle.net/x52Aa/

Hope I could help you at least with the most.
Cheers

Comment: Thanks very much to all who took the time to respond to my question.  Your help was much appreciated.  Sorry for my delayed response.  I think I put the wrong email address in, I didn't get a notification about my question. Thanks again.  You may have saved my sanity!  Mike H.